# users upvoting their own answers

Tags: discussion

I was just answering a question and saw the following happen (not the first time):

The user who left 2 comments got them both upvoted immediately. My answer and comment which i had posted just before him were almost identical and didn't get any upvotes.

Is there a way to see for SO if there are users who are using 2 or more accounts to upvote themselves all the time?

I mean if some users post an answer or comment and it's the same account upvoting those it should be pretty easy to filter out right?

Comment: Remember that comment upvotes are basically worthless except for one silver badge. It is thus rather unlikely for people to bother using sockpuppets to upvote their own comments.

Comment: @mmyers:  Are you sure?

Comment: @bobo: Yes, it doesn't give you any rep or something. The only advantage the commenter has is that it is more likely that their comments are seen.

Comment: @bobobobo: Believe me, if comment votes gave rep points, I would know. http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/101/all-time-insightful-comments ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember the random ordering on answers, some people don't take the time to look at the timestamp of the post.  Having said that there are sockpuppet accounts that usually get caught, but you could report really suspicious behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps your comment got overlooked, it happens.

Where exactly was it?

Perhaps you shouldn't be so quick to assume foul play.

Comment: Seeing the timeline, I'll bet that he's targeting on leppie's comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461203/casting-evalbitvalue-as-bool/3461255#3461255. It's definitely not sockpuppeting. Maybe at highest nepotism, but his comments are just nicely full to the point.

Comment: As i mentioned, this is just one of many cases where i have seen similar patterns. (Of could it could be my answers that are just off the point.)

Comment: @Jeroen: I don't want to debate about this, but, in this particular case, I can imagine someone likes Ieppie's comment more than yours, as it is, in a way, more ‘fun’.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the other user's comments had just a more strong bikeshed effect. It would encourage comment voting more.

If I am not wrong, there are already scripts to detect sockpuppeting in answers, so you don't need to worry about this.